# Print a dictionary without quote marks?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a non-nested dictionary:

```
>>> foo = {'a': 123, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}
```

I can print it:

```
>>> print(foo)
{'a': 123, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}
```

Is there any built-in or otherwise convenient method to print it in a single line without the quote marks and brackets?

```
a: 123, b: asdf, c: Hello, world!
```

This is assuming there are no nested dictionaries.

Comment: No. You have to write something yourself.

Comment: Side note: consider using Python 3, especially if you are just learning the language. Python 2 has reached end of life (as have Python 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5). At the time of writing, the latest version of Python is 3.8.5, and 3.9 has a release candidate out.

Comment: @Chris I am new to Python - is there something in the question which screams "Python 2"?

Comment: Python 3 no longer has a `print` statement; `print` is now a function, and must be called like one: `print(foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can make your own object:

```
class NicelyPrintingDict():
    def __init__(self, some_dictionary):
        self.some_dictionary = some_dictionary

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for key, value in self.some_dictionary.items():
            s += key + ': ' + str(value) + ' ' 
        return s.strip()
```

then, use it as follows:

```
foo = {'a': 123, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}
nice_foo = NicelyPrintingDict(foo)
print(nice_foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know what fields you are using all the time you can just do something like:

```
foo = {
    'a': 123,
    'b': 'asdf',
    'c': 'Hello, World!'
}

print(f"a: {foo['a']} b: {foo['b']} c: {foo['c']}")
```

> > > a: 123 b: asdf c: Hello, World!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the unwanted characters, and print it as you want, like this:

```
foo = {'a': 123, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}
print (str(foo).replace("{","").replace("'","").replace("}",""))
```

output:

```
a: 123, b: asdf, c: Hello, world!
```

pay attention, than whenever the characters `{`, `}` or `'` are part of the dict, that solution will fail

in more details - when calling to `str` function - each object can implement `__str__` function that return string (you can implement it by yourself for custom class). when take adventage of it - the str returned from the function can be treat as any other string and replace whatever you want to.

Comment: Thanks - this will work fine for my immediate purposes. Good to know there's not a more direct method I'm missing!

Comment: This depends on a lot of implementation details about when, exactly, single quotes will be used, e.g. try it with `foo = {'a': 123, 'b': 'a\'s\'df', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}`

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = {'a': 123, 'b': 'asdf', 'c': 'Hello, world!'}

for i,j in foo.items():
    print(i, ":", j, end = ",")

a : 123, b : asdf, c : Hello, world!,
```

Answer (score 0):

In the light of a few years' experience with Python:

```py
foo = {"a": 123, "b": "asdf", "c": "Hello, world!"}

print(", ".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in foo.items()))

# a: 123, b: asdf, c: Hello, world!
```

But more importantly... it's rarely necessary to just dump an arbitrary dictionary to the console, and when it is, the quote marks don't matter as much as I evidently thought they did in 2020 - and if it *is* necessary, I'd now create a function named `nice_print` or something, and use more, simpler lines to get the same result.